# Interpret Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am new to Access VBA and I want to know what this piece of code means?

```
[Formulare]![frm_Fahrzeug]![ID]
```

in a Where clause in a query

```
WHERE (((tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Konzept)=[Formulare]![frm_Fahrzeug]![ID]))
```

Comment: According to me: Formulare is the database name, frm_Fahrzeug is the table and Id is the columnName. SO the where clause checks whether the Konzept equals the id in that specified table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[Formulare]![frm_Fahrzeug]![ID]
```

In English:

```
Forms![frm_Fahrzeug]![ID]
```

It refers to the ID control or field of an open form called `frm_Fahrzeug`

Comment: A exclamation point refers to a field on a form's data source or a field within a table, but a period refers to a control on that form.  So, if the form name is like this "Form.Control" then it is the control on the form, but "Form!Field" refers to a field within the data source of the form, assuming the form is bound to a data source.  If you find errors using the ! symbol, it may be because the form is unbound and has no data tied to it.